# Query of Queries not matching empty string

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, coldfusion, qoq

I have a the output from a stored procedure on a SQL Server that I am running a query of queries on in CF9. I don't have any access to the stored procedure to make any changes, but I can output the contents.

My problem is that my QofQ is matching on several fields, one of which has a record that has an empty string in one of the fields that I'm matching on. The recordset should return that record, but it is not part of my recordset.

```
<cfquery name="test" dbtype="query">
SELECT * 
FROM dataLimited
WHERE market = <cfqueryparam value="" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
```

This returns zero records, even though I can see the record in the dump of the stored procedure.

Comment: Is it literally empty? Or does it potentially have spaces?

Comment: When I dump the results from the SP, the value is [empty string]

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure that the field has an empty string, and not null? CF does not do a good job of distinguishing between NULL and empty string, but query of queries [still respects the difference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/112-coldfusion-query-of-queries-uses-null-values-returns-empty-strings.htm). i.e.  Use the expression:

```
WHERE market IS NULL
```

Comment: OK, this turns out to be the issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it.  If my where clause is:

WHERE market IS NULL

then I get records.  

Considering the limitations on QoQ, is there a way to turn the NULL values into empty strings in the QofQ?

Comment: That can only be done within the db query/procedure OR by manually looping through the query and overwriting each value. However, if `WHERE Col IS NULL` returns the expected records, why do you need to convert them to empty strings? Just use `is null`. If for some reason you want to pick up *both* empty strings and nulls use both filters in the `WHERE` condition with the `OR` operator.

Comment: @Nathaniel, you can use `coalesce(market, '') as market` in your initial database query to turn those nulls into empty strings, but that is probably not the best approach. I would recommend sticking with `where market is null or market = ''`

Answer (score 0):

I'm looping over my QofQ to do subsequent QofQs, creating dynamic rows in a table. So my subsequent QofQs will have WHERE clauses that will match on the (possibly) NULL value or on a Non-NULL value. My solution has been to check the len() of the value and then in the subsequent query use:

```
<cfif len(data.market)> 
AND market = <cfqueryparam value="#data.market#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
<cfelse> 
AND market IS NULL 
</cfif>
```

Comment: Okay, that part was not clear from the initial question. *looping over my QofQ to do subsequent QofQs* Not related to the original question, but  try and avoid querying within a loop when possible. Since it requires executing/building a brand new query for *each row*, it is very inefficient and tends to scale poorly.